# Reading Characters to an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

First of all, I'm just a beginner and this is my first `C++` class

Say, if I have a array called the `result[500]`, I already have a input stream called `ifstream`, how can I store all the content (basically they are all numbers and operators and blanks between two, but we only want the numbers and operators) into array.

for example file is:

```
 3   4   2   1  -  5
```

will come to

```
result[]= {3,4,2,1,-,5}
```

Can anybody help me out with this problem?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What did you try so far? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: take a look at the c++ io tutorial http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: You will probably need a loop of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `std::fstream`:

1. Reading:

   ```
   std::ifstream ifs("data.txt");
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
   {
       ifs >> array[i];
   }
   ```
2. Storing:

   ```
   std::ofstream ofs("data.txt");
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
   {
       ofs << array[i] << " ";
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi~ thank you for your quick replay, when storing, I wanna filter all the white spaces, how can I do that?

Comment: @user1686630: std::ifstream will filter spaces for you, you don't have to do it by yourself

Answer (score 1):

you have to use for loop to iterate all elements and dump them to cout one by one appending any formatting as you wish

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `READ_FROM_STREAM` with your stream reading code, then that should do it more or less.

```
int i = 0;
int x = 0;
while(x = atoi(READ_FROM_STREAM)) {
  array[i++] = x;
}
```

You should probably also check that `i<MAX_ARR_SIZE` or similar.

Comment: In fact ignore this, nogard's answer is better.

Comment: it said identifier "READ_FROM STREAM" is undefined

Answer (score 1):

1. Read Each line
2. split each line on the empty space delimeter
3. store the elements in a stl list
4. use std::sort to sort the elements

Each of these lines are keywords for you to search around the internet and find the solution yourself so you'll be able to learn c++

good luck